# How to always show a keypad in react native?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, redux-form

I have a view, in which there is a redux form field linked to a text input.

First of all, is there a way to show that keypad on initial rendering without the sliding in animation?

Second, on finished editing, is there a way to still keep the keypad up there?

I have tried to set `blurOnSubmit` to `false` in `TextInput`, it seems to stop me from losing the focus by clicking outside.

Lastly, there is also a button on that page which will start a request with the input value, on resolved, a modal will slide up from the bottom to show a success screen. This modal is implemented using `react-navigation`. The modal is a relatively small rectangle shape with the rest part transparent. So users can see the original page even when the success modal is up. In this case, is there a way to always show the keypad in the original screen even when the modal is up?

Comment: try to call `focus()` fo your textInput on `componentWillReceiveProps` event

Comment: Thanks, Hend. This kind of works with 2 other issues. The first one is when I click an button outside of the textinput, the keypad flicks a little bit, I think that is caused by the focus call on each WillReceiveProps. The other issue is when the modal is up, the keypad seems to be on the same layer as the modal rather than on the same layer as the TextInput.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all, is there a way to show that keypad on initial rendering without the sliding in animation?

No. React Native doesn't support a way to disable the slide animation.

> Second, on finished editing, is there a way to still keep the keypad up there?

If the TextInput is being rendered inside a ScrollView, add `keyboardShouldPersistTaps=handled`. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#keyboardshouldpersisttaps. It will hold the focus.

Comment: Thank you, Estevao. This works well for single page, once the modal comes in, it still hides the keypad.

Comment: The only way to keep the keyboard opened is by keeping the focus in the TextInput. If TextInput loses the focus, the keyboard will close right away.